# How to retrieve a NSDictionary on the php side

Tags: php, ios

I am sending a `POST` request to a php API, the request contains an `NSDictionary` with two keys/values:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:amounts,@"amounts",[NSNumber numberWithInt:cId],@"user_id", nil];//Amount is an NSMutableArray

[[APIClient sharedInstance] postPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@register.php",prefixURL] parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", text);//the response is valid
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Failure: %@",error.userInfo);
}];
```

However, the issue is that I cannot find a way to retrieve the parameters (amounts and user_id) in the PHP side. I am not a PHP guy so would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Is it `POST` or `GET` request? If first, then in `$_POST`, if second, then in `$_GET`.You may also try to look in `$_REQUEST`. Use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump) with variables, I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using AFNetworking, the keys and values from your `parameters` dictionary are being placed into the request itself.  When you call `postPath`, it sends a POST request to the server.  So you can simply read the values with `$_POST['amounts']` and `$_POST['user_id']`.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of sending the NSDictionary, first serialise it to JSON first, then just send the JSON.

Something like:

```
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDictionary
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&jsonError];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"json"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

Comment: I agree, PHP can't natively handle NSDictionaries, but you can get classes to serialise to JSON and PHP understands (or can handle in some capacity) JSON